# How to create new columns more conveniently with partially matched names?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

Below code  create new variable  `a_new/b_new/c_new` , but have to input code in mutate one by one. Is there any convenient way ?

In actual, I have to create many variable ,for instance `a_new/b_new/..../z_new`. I don't want to input the variable calculating code one by one.

```r
library(tidyverse)  

test_data <- data.frame(a=c(1:3),
                        b=c(3:5),
                        c=c(1:3),
                        a_increase=c(1:3)/100,
                        b_increase=c(3:5)/100,
                        c_increase=c(6:8)/100)

test_data %>% mutate(
  a_new =a* a_increase,
  b_new =b* b_increase,
  c_new =c* c_increase
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `across` to specify your columns of interest, then `get` the corresponding columns that end with the string "_increase". Finally, use the `.names` argument to set new column names.

```r
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% 
  mutate(across(a:c, ~get(paste0(cur_column(), "_increase")) * .x, .names = "{.col}_new"))

  a b c a_increase b_increase c_increase a_new b_new c_new
1 1 3 1       0.01       0.03       0.06  0.01  0.09  0.06
2 2 4 2       0.02       0.04       0.07  0.04  0.16  0.14
3 3 5 3       0.03       0.05       0.08  0.09  0.25  0.24
```

Comment: cur_column() means  a:c ? Thanks1

Comment: `cur_column` returns the column names specified in `across`. So in this case it returns "a", "b" and "c". That's why we can use `paste0` on `cur_column()` to get the "_increase" columns.

Comment: test_data %>% mutate(across(a:c, ~ get(paste0(c('a','b','c'),'_increase'))*.x,.names = "{.col}_new"))    @benson23 when use  【paste0(c('a','b','c'),'_increase')】to create variable name, the the code can't work .What's wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: @anderwyang How can it `get` all three columns at once? You can't do that.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your replay!